# WooCommerce order details after checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi im creating my custom woocommerce theme and i want to display to user his order details like order id, total price etc. after checkout. Currently when user click on pay button on checkout page (shop.com/checkout/ where he can fill out billing information) my url change to shop.com/checkout/order-received/98/?key=wc_order_5a70a40f30bde and order appears in woocommerce admin panel so everything works fine, but the user still see checkout page (billing form etc), not the order details page. So the only thing that's change is url, not the page.

Here is my checkout page code:

https://pastebin.com/R3kyE6TW

```
<?php
        $checkout = WC()->checkout;
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', $checkout );
        if ( ! $checkout->is_registration_enabled() && $checkout->is_registration_required() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_must_be_logged_in_message', __( 'You must be logged in to checkout.', 'woocommerce' ) );
            return;
        }
        ?>

        <form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <?php if ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields() ) : ?>
                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' ); ?>
                    <div class="" id="customer_details">
                        <div class="">
                            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>
                        </div>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="woocomerce_additional_custom">
                            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping' ); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php _e( 'Your order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review' ); ?>
                <div id="order_review" class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order">
                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' ); ?>
                </div>
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review' ); ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', $checkout ); ?>
```

So how can display to user his order details? Is there any shortcode for order details page like there is for checkout page [woocommerce_checkout] where i can past woocommerce/order/order-details.php code?

Comment: Normally it changes in "order-received" page as it uses the template checkout/thankyou.php that load order details (through templates located in "orders" folder)… If you don't have that is because **you have maid wrong custom changes** (or other changes maid by the theme authors)… You should revert those wrong changes and find another "clean" way… This should be done step by step, testing everything between each change you are making.

Comment: Ok but my question is, should I add another page in wordpress to which i will redirect user after checkout? or woocommerce is doing it for me and i only need to setup checkout page and woocomerce will generate order details template ? Everything that you see in code is pasted from woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php

Comment: Woocommerce is doing everything and it depend on the payment gateway settings (in both sides woo and the payment gateway platform)